# Why do i get a DriveApp error when connecting to a shared drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to run a script that reads all the files in a fixed directory, however i am failing at the first hurdle with defining the ID. I copied the shared link and pasted the relevant details into the variable but keep getting the message

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.

It's probably something really simple, but whichever way I change i  still get the same error, is there any reason why you cannot connect to a shared drive ? I have permissions for that drive ?

I am trying to run a script that reads all the files in a fixed directory, however i am failing at the first hurdle with defining the ID. I copied the shared link and pasted the relevant details into the variable but keep getting the message

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.

It's probably something really simple, but whichever way I change i  still get the same error, is there any reason why you cannot connect to a shared drive ? I have permissions for that drive ?

````
function combineFiles() {
 
  var driveID       = "1U4q5e-6bTxUrqC1yvyGAYQCii4aKcbwA?usp";
  var folder        = DriveApp.getFolderById(driveID);

  var folder          = DriveApp.getFolderById('1U4q5e-6bTxUrqC1yvyGAYQCii4aKcbwA?usp');

  
   Logger.log(folder)


 var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
 var file          = filesIterator.next();
 var fn            = file.getName();
} ```

``` Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp ```
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What is `a fixed directory`? And, can I ask you about the relationship between `a fixed directory` and `a shared drive` and your showing script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need use only ID folder, try

```
function combineFiles() {
 
  var driveID       = "1U4q5e-6bTxUrqC1yvyGAYQCii4aKcbwA";
  var folder        = DriveApp.getFolderById(driveID);
  
  Logger.log(folder)

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).